# How does empty List equality work?

Tags: scala, types, equals, equality, subtyping

Does the `==` operator really compare List by content? Especially with regards to empty List?

The following comparisons work as expected

```
List("A", "B", "C") == "ABC".split("").toList // true
List() == List() // true
List.empty[String] == List.empty[String] // true
```

However, empty list comparison of different type gives confusing result:

```
List.empty[String] == List.empty[Int] // true: on different types?
```

EDIT: in the initial question, I made a misleading test case which has been clarified by Andrey. Thanks. Reproduced here

```
val emptyStrSplit = "".split("").toList // List("") and not List() as displayed in Console
List.empty[String] == emptyStrSplit // false: b/c List() != List("")
```

Comment: `"".split("").toList` is not `List()`. It's `List("")`. Does the question still ask anything significant after you remove the false assumption that `"".split("")` is empty?

Comment: `toString` is awkward and ambiguous - the empty string in `List("")` is invisible in the printed output, so it looks like `List()`.

Comment: Hi, oups got fooled by the output `List()` of `"".split("").toList`  and failed to check the size, Thank you. So the question is pretty much silly. The only interesting portion now becomes how to check two empty lists of different types `List.empty[T1] == List.empty[T2]`. Will edit the question accordingly

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- `List.empty[String]` is the singleton object `Nil`, which extends `List[Nothing]` (covariantly, subtype of `List[String]`).
- `List.empty[Int]` is the singleton object `Nil`, which extends `List[Nothing]` (covariantly, subtype of `List[Int]`).
- Every singleton object is equal to itself.
- Therefore, `Nil == Nil` gives true.

So, essentially, you have a single object `Nil` which is simultaneously of type `List[String]` and of type `List[Int]`. That's what you get if you have subtyping. I don't see anything strange or contradictory here.

If you want to ensure that the types are the same, you can use `implicit` evidence of type `A =:= B` with default value `null`, and then check whether a non-`null` evidence is provided by the compiler:

```
def eqSameType[A, B](a: A, b: B)(implicit ev: A =:= B = null) = 
  if (ev == null) false else a == b
```

Example:

```
scala> eqSameType(List.empty[Int], List.empty[String])
res4: Boolean = false
```

Comment: Oh now I see why. Thanks for the clarification. But still at the business logic level. It is desirable that `List.empty[String] == List.empty[Int]` yields a `false` albeit using a customized comparator. See complete answer below

Comment: @Polymerase No, it's not necessarily "desirable". Some people believe that it is more desirable if `x == y` for `x` and `y` of different types wouldn't typecheck at all: [Multiversal equality](https://dotty.epfl.ch/docs/reference/multiversal-equality.html).

Comment: Even better! Also passes Brian's test case `eqSameType(List.empty[List[String]], List.empty[List[Int]]) // false` So many good things in the same day :-). What is the syntax `A =:= B = null` called? I'd like to read further documentation.

Comment: @Polymerase `=:=` is a binary infix type constructor (sugar for `=:=[A, B]`), `= null` is a default value for argument `ev` of type `A =:= B`. I think the `=:=` thingies are called "generalized type constraints".

Answer (score 4):

Even ignoring the type erasure issue and "they are actually the same object" issue, documentation for `equals` on `Seq` states:

> `def equals(that: Any): Boolean`
>
> The equals method for arbitrary sequences.
>
> returns: true if that is a sequence that has the same elements as this sequence in the same order, false otherwise

which makes all empty sequences equal: they have the same elements in the same order, namely none. Empty `List` is equal to empty `Vector`, `Queue`, `Stream`, etc. etc.

You may also be interested in libraries providing type-safe equality, e.g. [Scalactic](http://doc.scalactic.org/3.0.1/#org.scalactic.TripleEqualsSupport), [Scalaz](http://eed3si9n.com/learning-scalaz/Equal.html), etc.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to Andrey's answer, even if `List.empty[T]` (or `List[T]()`) did return a new instance of `List`, you still should expect empty lists of various types to be equal due to type erasure. For example, take `ListBuffer`, whose `empty` method does return a new `ListBuffer` every time:

```
import scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer
ListBuffer.empty[Int] == ListBuffer.empty[String]
```

If you want a way to detect when two lists have different compile-time types, you can use [`TypeTags`](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/reflection/typetags-manifests.html):

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe.{ TypeTag, typeTag }

def equalAndSameType[A: TypeTag, B: TypeTag](as: Seq[A], bs: Seq[B]) =
  typeTag[A] == typeTag[B] && as == bs

equalAndSameType(List.empty[Int], List.empty[String]) // returns false
```

I'm not sure when this would be useful, though.

Comment: Oh cool, look like we came up with the same idea within a few seconds. BTW can you please elaborate about the usage of `TypeTag` vs `ClassTag` ?

Comment: @Polymerase See the link to the docs. Typetags have more information about generics, so a classtag-based solution will fail on more deeply nested generics. Consider `equalAndSameType(List.empty[List[String]], List.empty[List[Int]])`; it's actually a corner case where your answer fails.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: this implementation using `ClassTag` is not good enough. Brian's answer using `TypeTag` is better.

Although Andrey's answer make perfect sense from the Scala point of view. I feel it makes more business sense to have `List.empty[String] == List.empty[Int]` to be false rather than true. Below is a custom comparator using context bound to support the below. Not sure if it's the most elegant way.

```
import scala.reflect.{ClassTag, classTag}

def customCompareLists[T1: ClassTag, T2: ClassTag](l1: List[T1], l2: List[T2]): Boolean = {
  classTag[T1] == classTag[T2] && l1 == l2
}

customCompareLists(List(), List()) // true
customCompareLists(List.empty[Double], List.empty[Double]) // true
customCompareLists(List.empty[String], List.empty[Int]) // false
customCompareLists(List(1,2), List("A")) // false
customCompareLists(List(1,2), List(1,2)) // true

// FAILED on this case
customCompareLists(List.empty[List[String]], List.empty[List[Int]]) // true: INCORRECT
```

Comment: I suspect "it makes more business sense" depends on your use case.